# Is it safe to move from the top/front of a STL stack/queue?

Tags: c++, stack, move

The question holds for both stacks and queues, but I will just allude to a stack here for simplicity.

Assuming that we push non-const objects into `std::stack`, is it safe, when we're popping from the stack, to move the object at the top of the stack into a temporary variable before popping like in the following:

```
std::stack<std::string> st;
st.emplace("asdf");
auto popped = std::move(st.top());
st.pop();
```

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh I will edit that part out of my question.

Comment: @rafix07 Why do I need to define or derive anything for `stack` in this case? Since `top()` returns a non-const reference, couldn't we simply use `std::move` to cast the top object into an x-value and use the move assignment operator or constructor (in the above case) to initialize `popped`?

Comment: I think that `stack::pop` is actually undefined behavior on empty stack. I assume that because [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/) it is written that _Exception Safety : Provides the same level of guarantee as the operation performed on the underlying container object._  By default the container is `std::deque` ([ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/)).  This all implies that `stack::pop` internally calls `deque::pop_back`. And [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/pop_back/) it is written to have undefined behavior when `deque` is empty.

Comment: Continuing my previous comment... When you are using `std::move` on `std::stack::top`, which has just one element, then surely the statement calling `stack::pop` will be an undefined behavior. It doesn't tells how correct is moving the top of a stack. It just tells how wrong it is to do so when the stack has just one element  and you know you will be popping that!

Comment: @brc-dd `std::move` does not destroy the source object. It still exists, albeit in an undefined (but valid) state. So, the follow up `pop` is valid (and usually necessary!) operation that destroyes the "zombie" object left behind by `std::move`.

Comment: @CygnusX1 Okay got that point. So everything just makes it a valid and safe call...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is safe, if you use the non-const version of the stack. (For a const version of the stack, you will most likely copy the object or get a compile error)

Since `std::stack` returns a non-const reference to an object, you are free to modify it. This includes moving out from the object.

Recall that moving from an object keeps it in a valid state (at least, if the class is implemented correctly). It does *not* destroy it. It is still there on the top of your stack. It just doesn't contain any definite value. The follow-up `pop` will call a proper destructor on it without a problem.

Note, that the moving-out is *not* allowed for `std::priority_queue`, because that kind of container actually cares about the contents. And - for that reason it just returns a const-reference, which cannot be used to move things out from it.

---

In response to Iamanon's observation that `std::move` can be perfomed on a const reference. In fact you *can* do that. Usually it is not useful though and it will usually reduce to a copy, instead of move. Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>

class Foo {
    public:
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "created\n";
        }
    ~Foo() {
        std::cout << "destroyed  " << value << "\n";
    }
    Foo(const Foo& other) : value(other.value) {
        std::cout << "copied\n";
    }
    Foo(Foo&& other) : value(other.value) {
        other.value++;
        std::cout << "moved\n";
    }
    Foo(const Foo&& other) : value(other.value) {
        std::cout << "const-moved\n";
    }    
    int value = 0;
};

int main()
{
std::stack<Foo> st;
st.emplace();
const std::stack<Foo>& cst = st;
auto popped = std::move(cst.top());
st.pop();
}
```

If you run the above, a const-moved version will be used. However, as you implement your const-move constructor you will realize that you cannot really do much better than your regular copy constructor. That is because `other` remain immutable. For example, you cannot take ownership of anything `other` holds, and reset it within `other`.

And if you remove the const-move constructor, the compiler will use the regular copy constructor.

If the copy-constructor is deleted, and only move-constructor is provided - *then* the compiler will throw an error at you.

Comment: This discussion has me thinking, when would we actually have a `const` stack object? This would be the only situation where the `const` version of `std::stack::top()` will be invoked? It would seem kind of pointless to have a container like `stack` ever be constant?

Comment: Also, I think even if there wasn't a non-const version of `top()`, the code in the OP would still compile, but `std::move` would be pointless because it would be applied to a `const T&` object, which I think just results in no casting, and hence a copy is made when initializing `popped`, rather than the move constructor.

Comment: @lamanon `std::move` changes the source object into a "zombie" object. You cannot do that on a `const&`

Comment: @Iamanon omg.... your nickname starts with I not L :P (pinged you correctly this time)

Comment: Funny thing I also couldn't remember if it was an i or L. Also, right I understand that it changes the source, but if the source is const, it still seems to compile. For example, the following compiles: ```T j; const T &i = j; std::move(i); ```